# Trouoble with Ajax submitting to database

Tags: php, ajax, database

I have this form:

```
<form method = \"get\" action = \"\" onsubmit = \"return addBeer('$user','$id','$name','$abv','$ibu','$icon','$style','$brewery','$breweryID','$icon')\" >

<p> <input type = \"submit\" value = \"Go Fishing\" /> </p>

</form>
```

which calls this JavaScript function:

```
function addBeer(user,id,bname,abv,ibu,icon,bstyle,brewery,breweryID,icon)
        {
            //get elements

            alert('userID' + user);

            alert('beerid'+id); 

            alert('beername'+bname);        

            alert('style'+bstyle);

            alert('brewery'+brewery);

            alert('abv'+abv);

            alert('ibu'+ibu);

            alert('brewery id'+ breweryID);

            alert('icon'+icon);


            //run ajax
            var ajaxSettings2 = 
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "addBeer.php",
                data: "uID="+user+"&bID="+id+"&bName="+bname+"&bStyle="+bstyle+"&bBrewery="+brewery+"&abv="+abv+"&ibu="+ibu+"&breweryID="+breweryID,
                success: function() 
                {
                    $('#sbutton').remove();
                    alert('Load was performed.');
                },

                error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert("error: " + error); }   };
            $.ajax(ajaxSettings2);

        }
```

All the alerts work so I know for a fact that the information is getting passed fom the form to the function, but it fails on the ajax call to addBeer.php because it runs the error function and pop up the error alert. Unfortunetley nothing is reported in the pop up.

This is the addBeer.php file that is called to add to the database:

```
<?php

                require_once('myConnectDB.inc.php');
                require_once('page.inc.php');

                session_start();





                        //add beer to database code
                        $userID = $_POST['uID'];
                        $beerName = $_POST['bName'];
                        $beerID = $_POST['bid'];
                        $brewery = $_POST['bBrewery'];
                        $style = $_POST['bStyle'];

                        $abv = $_POST['abv'];
                        $ibu = $_POST['ibu'];
                        $breweryID = $_POST['breweryID'];
                        //$icon = $_POST['icon'];


                        //get brewery icon
                        $uri3 = "http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/brewery/$breweryID?key=myKey&format=json";
                        $response3 = file_get_contents($uri3);
                        //parse xml
                        $myBrew = json_decode($response3);
                        $iconBrew = $myBrew->data->images->medium;

                        //add above data to database
                        $db = new myConnectDB();

                        $beerName = $db->real_escape_string($beerName);
                        $beerID = $db->real_escape_string($beerID);
                        $brewery = $db->real_escape_string($brewery);
                        $style = $db->real_escape_string($style);
                        $userID = $db->real_escape_string($userID);
                        $abv = $db->real_escape_string($abv);
                        $ibu = $db->real_escape_string($ibu);
                        $breweryID = $db->real_escape_string($breweryID);           
                        $icon = $db->real_escape_string($icon); 




                        $query3 = "INSERT INTO tableName (userID,beerID,beerName,beerStyle,beerBrewery,abv,ibu,breweryID,icon, brewIcon) VALUES ($userID, '$beerID', '$beerName', '$style' , '$brewery', '$abv','$ibu','$breweryID', '$icon', '$iconBrew')";
                        $db->query($query3);


                ?>
```

I took out my api key and table name for security.

I have checked the network tab in chrome under inspect element and when I click on addBeer.php call and look under headers it shows in form data that the information is being passed.

**Update:**

I am escaping my quotes because its being printed from php

Comment: You might want to prevent the form from submitting by returning false from addBeer

Comment: thanks for that tip, I forgot about that and was wondering why my page was still refreshing.

Comment: Hi Mike, can you edit your post and explain why you are escaping the quotes in your form HTML? This is quite unclear.

Comment: @jmort253 thanks for the suggestion, I added your requested info above.

Comment: Also, have you tried pulling out all of the DB code and just echoing back what you received from the AJAX? This will further help narrow down the source of the error so that you don't have to post your entire project. ;) For instance, if you don't get an error without DB code, the problem is in the DB code, if you still get that error without it, then the problem is possibly in the AJAX. Also, what does the NET tab say in your debugger? Are you getting a response from the server?

Comment: @jmort253 so I tried pretty much taking all the code out of addBeer.php except for a line to print some text and ajax still ran the error function. 

In the response in inspect element in chrome it gave nothing. So maybe its something in the ajax or the form that is giving it errors.

Comment: I'd suggest continuing to play around with it from there. Change to a GET, then try a test without the query parameters. Run the jQuery AJAX function from your JavaScript console so you can tweak it and make real-time adjustments. Also, if you have any server-side logging on, this may be helpful..... As you learn more, update your question with an [edit], which will bump it back to the top and get more eyes on the problem. Good luck! :)

Comment: I have been able to fix my problem but I honestly do not know why it works. I will look over my results and see if I can post the reasoning soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots and lots of frustration, I figured out my problem. The information I was sending, I was querying from another database and all that info was not always complete.

If I clicked submit and it and one of the variables in the function call was an empty string it did not like it.

Answer (score -1):

You have your method as `GET` in the form but `POST` in your Ajax.

Comment: I changed it to a post and it did not work. Which I don't think this should have solved the problem because the form isn't really submitting to anything just calling a function.

Comment: hmm maybe because you wrote return in front of addBeer() also if it is not inserting into the database its maybe because you didn't add single quotes around $userID in your insert query hope this fixes it

Comment: I dont believe I need single quotes on the $userID as its an int not a string. I gave it a try anyway and it didnt change a thing.

Comment: so what is the exact problem, does it not insert or does ajax not send your info to the php file?

Comment: I am pretty sure it sends to the php file based on what I said above in my post in reading the inspect elements in chrome of my page. But an error must be thrown someplace because it goes to the error function in my ajax call.